I've built 3 portals using angular each have 3 folders inside app folder core, feature & shared, core & shared have same code, how can I reuse code
I've built 3 portals using angular which runs on 3 different subdomain, code wise each have 3 folders inside app folder core, feature & shared, core & shared have same code, how can I reuse core and shared folder code so I don't have to copy paste it to other portals.
looking for some assistance on this on Architectual level, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.
